# Issue with ModelBinding a List<int> correctly on RedirectToAction()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, generic-list

I have a `form` with a plain vanilla multi-select listbox that I use for filtering.

So, by standard design, I do the filter as a GET operation. So the form submit results in a perfectly acceptable URL:

```
http://example.com/Matrix?role=1&role=6&role=2
```

Which binds perfectly to the `roles` argument:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ViewResult Matrix(List<int> roles) { ... }
```

Now the returned filtered view contains a form that needs to be `post`ed to the server as it contains data mods defined in a `CustomViewModel`. Again the form is posted to the same URL and the binding occurs perfectly:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Matrix(CustomViewModel vm, List<int> roles)
{
    ...
    //Passing the list 'roles' untouched directly to the redirect
    //Problem sirens set off!!
    return RedirectToAction(MVC.T4Path.To.Matrix(roles));
}
```

The problem arises on trying to perform a redirect. Now logically it seems to be a straight-forward redirect with `roles` passed as an argument to retain the filters. But the resultant GET request is:

```
http://example.com/Matrix?roleSelector=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.Int32%5D
```

**Why is this happening? What can I do to get the generated URL to be similar to the pretty one?**

The work around I am using at the moment is to pass the data back using `TempData`, but this causes the data to disappear from the URL and although the filter is retained, the form itself is empty/reset.

Answer (score 0):

If I read sources correctly, even path building process is rather smart, it still do simple `Convert.ToString()` on building query parameters:

```
stringBuilder1.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(str));
stringBuilder1.Append('=');
stringBuilder1.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToString(obj, (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

So you cannot do much to make your url pretty. The only option I see in this case is to build your url manualy and pass it in `return Redirect(url)`